# How I POST data from input and result data display to component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, angular-httpclient

I have problem with display data in component who I POST from input to server. In input I need enter companyId and after POST request server return specific data from product. In console I get response from server that it is **undefined** but in network tab I see that POST is successful and data came from server and I don't know how to catch and display them.

JSON:

```
{"products":[{"productId":"4","productName":"Trucker Classic 6","productCode":"TGP11136C","productGroupMiddleName":"Truckih","resourceUrl":"\/Product\/4","installmentTypes":[{"installmentTypeId":"1","installmentTypeName":"Single premium"},{"installmentTypeId":"2","installmentTypeName":"Annual instalments"}]}, {"productId":"5","productName":"Trucken Classic 8","productCode":"TGP48145C","productGroupMiddleName":"Truck4","resourceUrl":"\/Product\/5","installmentTypes":[{"installmentTypeId":"1","installmentTypeName":"Single premium"},{"installmentTypeId":"2","installmentTypeName":"Annual instalments"}]},{"productId":"6","productName":"Truckel Classic 6","productCode":"TAP60562C","productGroupMiddleName":"Truck8","resourceUrl":"\/Product\/6","installmentTypes":[{"installmentTypeId":"1","installmentTypeName":"Single premium"},{"installmentTypeId":"2","installmentTypeName":"Annual instalments"}]},
```

Code:

***component.ts***

```
testForm: FormGroup;
product: Products[] = [];

 constructor(
    private testService: testService,
  ) {
  }

ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.testForm = new FormGroup({
      productId: new FormControl()
    });
  }

submit() {
    this.testService.searchByProduct(this.testForm.value).subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
        this.product = response.products;
        console.log(this.product);
        },
        (error: any) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
  }
```

***component.html***

```
    <form fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" [formGroup]="testForm" (submit)="submit()" class="form">
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>ID product</mat-label>
        <input matInput id="productId" type="number" formControlName="productId">
      </mat-form-field>
    
      <button mat-raised-button class="form-button" color="primary" type="submit">search</button>
    </form>

**<!--- I NEED TO SHOW RESPONSE DATA HERE --->**
        <div *ngFor="let i of product">
          <p>{{i.productId}}</p>
          <p>{{i.productName}}</p>
        </div>
```

***model.ts***

```
export class Products {
  productId: number;
  productName: string;
  productCode: string;
}
```

***service.ts***

```
searchByProduct(productId) {
    return this.http.post(environment.ApiUrl + '/api/urlapi', productId, {responseType: 'text'});
  }
```

Comment: You want to get data, so I don't think it's a POST request, but a GET. Also, I've created a [minimal stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lv6d6a?file=src/app/app.component.ts) with your example and it's actually working. I've just kept the first product from your JSON. I think the JSON is not formatted finely.

Comment: the comma in your code "private testService: testService," in the constructor has to be removed since only one private variable is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several issues, but I'm not sure why response should be undefined.

- your `searchByProduct` method returns an `Observable` of type `string` because you passed `responseType: 'text'` in the second parameter, but you want the products as Javascript objects. Remove the `responseType` and the response will be parsed as objects
- I think `this.testForm.value` will evaluated to `{ productId: **/some number**/}` not the number directly